# Generate OTP IN SPRING MVC FROM

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, one-time-password

I'm developing a Banking Application and want to generate OTP if the user forgot's ID. I have tried to do set Request Mapping in Controller Class of OTP Success but it show's error. This is my COde I want  to generate some random way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/otpSuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void send(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
        String numbers = "0123456789";
        String acn=req.getParameter("acc");
        Random rndm_method = new Random(); 
          char[] otp = new char[6];
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
            { 
               otp[i]=numbers.charAt(rndm_method.nextInt(numbers.length()));
            }
            Session session=this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            Query q=session.createQuery("select email from Student where accno=:n");
            q.setParameter("n", acn);
            List<String>  l=q.list();
            String  body=otp.toString();
            String host="smtp.gmail.com";  
           final String user="codingbloke90@gmail.com";  
           final String password="XXXXXXXX";  //My mail's password

      String to=l.get(0);

       //Get the session object  
       Properties props = new Properties();  
       props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
       //below is mycom.infotech.controller.FundController.send(FundController.java:111) actual line which is showing error 
       javax.mail.Session session1 =  javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
          }  
        });  

       //Compose the message  
        try {  

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session1);  
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
         message.setSubject("Verification");  
         message.setText(body);  

        //send the message  
         Transport.send(message);  

         System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

         } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}  


 }  
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0
    java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    com.infotech.controller.FundController.send(FundController.java:111)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.21
```

Can somebody suggest any changes in the OTP format I have or should use generation of OTP elsewhere .It is showing error on line 111 which I have shown in the comment and also mentioned the error (LINE 111) code part here

```
javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
             protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
             }
          });
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with OTP. Read the error stack trace very carefully instead of trying to guess what the problem might be. The problem is that you're trying to access the first element of a list that is empty, at line 111 of FundController.java. So, start from there to fix your logic.

Comment: Which part of Logic of generating OTP? @JBNizet

Comment: You haven't read my comment. So I repeat. The problem is that you're trying to access the first element of a list that is empty, at line 111 of FundController.java. So the very first thing you must do is to find line 111 of your file. Then wonder what list you're accessing at that line, if it is normal or not that this list is empty, and what you should do to fix or circumvent that. So, what is line 111? What is the empty list? Where does it come from? Why is it empty? Is it normal or not?

Comment: @JBNizet please check the edit

Comment: That's not line the line which causes the exceptin. You have probably modified the code since this exception was thrown. Again, read the error message. It happens when you try to access element at index 0 of a list: `String to=l.get(0);`

Comment: @JBNizet I'm changing the code still changes are not reflecting and showing same error can you suggest something because after changing the code there is a brace @ line 111 and the same error is coming .I have restarted my server and even switched the workspace and done work with new server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196780/discussion-between-shivam-sharma-and-jb-nizet).